# Access to NTFS volume from KNOPPIX live cd

Tags: windows-7, linux, ntfs, data-recovery

Im trying to recover some data from my friends laptop, since it wont boot from the harddisk anymore. From the knoppix cd i can find harddrive but when i try to access it im asked for a password. However dont know the password I have tried the password from his windows login but that doesnt work. Is there another way to access the drive so i dont have to use a password? If possible i would like to avoid removing the harddrive from the laptop. The installed OS is win7

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are being asked for root's password to mount a NTFS drive. If that is the case, using a Live CD open a root shell from applications menu and type 
`passwd`
, you will be asked to enter and confirm root's new password. You can the enter that password when asked while trying to mount that windows drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting "sudo" before the command. The mount command requires superuser rights, but on Live CD they are available to anyone. And mount it with -t ntfs3g, it's the best NTFS driver for Linux.